# Does the equation have a real solution...please help!

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Suppose that $c_0, c_1, \cdots , c_n$ are real numbers and that $c_0 + \frac {c_1}{2} + \frac {c_2}{3} + \cdots + \frac {c_{n-1}}{n} + \frac {c_n}{n+1} = 0$. Prove that the equation: $c_0 + (c_1)x + \cdots + (c_{n-1})x^{n-1} + (c_n)x^n = 0$ has at least one real solution between 0 and 1.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Apply Rolle's theorem to the function $$f(x) = \frac{c_{n}}{n+1} x^{n+1} + \frac{c_{n-1}}{n} \cdot x^{n} + \cdots + c_{0}\cdot x$$